# 2011 Honda Civic: new battery, alarm will not stop

Tags: honda, battery, civic, alarm

2011 Honda Civic. Car was sitting for multiple months. Car battery was dead once tried to use of course, alarm was set when car battery died. New car battery purchased due to battery being bad. After new car battery was installed. Car alarm will not stop going off which keeps the engine immobilization active. Had issues with key fob prior to this. Key fob wouldn’t work, so new battery was put into key fob. Key fob still does not work to shut off alarm. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You have tried putting the key in the ignition and turning it to the run position?

Comment: Yes I have put it in run and left there and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your car is equipped with both an immobilizer and a theft deterrent alarm (the beep beep one). Just the theft alarm beeping WILL NOT prevent starting, only the immobilizer does that. (Assuming this is the stock alarm and not aftermarket.)

To disable beep beep alarm you must either cycle the key in a door lock or use the keyless entry buttons on a programmed remote. Cycling the ignition will not work for most honda's.

If your keyless entry controls are not working its the fobs battery, fobs damaged or it has lost programming.

You should also see if the immobilizer is still programmed. (Honda's like to loose immobilizer memory with bad/disconnected batteries). To check, turn your ignition to the ON position (do not crank) and Look for a green light with a key symbol. If this light comes on and goes out then the immobilizer is programmed. If this light flashes then your key is damaged or the key, micu, immobilizer or ecu has lost part of the immobilizer chains sync data and will need to be reprogrammed by a good auto locksmith or auto shop. The keyless entry controls are programmed via obd2 at the same time as the immobilizer for this year Honda.

If your key is still programmed with immobilizer then you can also try to manually program the keyless entry controls:

1. Turn ignition switch to ON
2. Press the LOCK on remote
3. Turn ignition switch off
4. Turn ignition switch to ON
5. Press the LOCK on remote
6. Turn ignition off
7. Turn ignition switch to ON
8. Press the LOCK on remote, You will hear the door locks work.
9. Press the LOCK on remote
10. Turn ignition off and your done.